# In how many ways can we split $80$ persons in a $5$ wagon train such that :

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In how many ways can we distribute $80$ persons in a $5$ wagon train such that :
>
> $a)$ exactly $15$ go into the first wagon
>
> $b)$ exactly $15$ go into one wagon

For $a$) we have $\binom{80}{15}$ ways to choose $15$ persons for one wagon and for the rest of $65$ we use the stars and bars problem? How to approach $b)$ then ?

Comment: Does b) mean *exactly* one wagon has exactly 15? or does it mean *at least* one wagon has exactly 15?

Comment: At least one wagon has exactly 15

Comment: @SADBOYS Have you the result for a)? I am not sure what "split" means here.

Comment: "distribute" should have been the word, sorry. And I don't have the result this is from an exam paper but I asured it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the people are distinguishable, as most people are...

(a) There are $\binom{80}{15}$ ways to choose the people which go in the first wagon, then $4^{65}$ ways to distribute the others (each person can go in one of four wagons).

(b) Use inclusion exclusion. For each wagon, count the number of ways where that particular wagon has $15$ people. Then subtract the doubly counted arrangements where two particular wagons have $15$ people, then add back in the triply counted ones, etc.

Comment: Isn't $4^{65}$ like too much for $a)$? because if person $a$ $b$ and $c$ let's say are in a wagon it's the same as person $b$ $a$ and $c$ being in a wagon?

Comment: $4^{65}$ does not assign any order to the people within a wagon. Imagine the 65 people lined up and got in a wagon one at a time. $\tag*{}$Person 1 has four choices.$\tag*{}$ Person 2 has four choices.$\tag*{}$ $\vdots$ $\tag*{}$Person 65 has four choices. @SADBOYS

Answer (score 3):

I think that here we should consider the $80$ persons as "indistinguishable objects". So the answer for  a) should be:
$$|W_1|=\left|\{(x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb{N}^4:x_2+x_3+x_3+x_5=65\}\right|\\=\binom{65+3}{3}=50116$$
which has been evaluated by using the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two).

As regards $b)$ consider the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):
$$|W_1\cup W_2\cup W_3\cup W_4\cup W_5|=\dots$$
where $W_i$ is the set of arrangements such that the $i$-th wagon has exactly 15 persons.